# sed, awk, perl or lex: find strings by prefix+regex, ignoring rest of input

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, lex

I need to find strings with a certain prefix, followed by a regexp, in a bunch of files, but ignore the rest of the input (including the content of the line before the prefix, and after the end of the matching regexp).

What's the best tool for the job?  `grep` finds complete lines; `sed` is usually used just for editing and select-and-replace; `awk`?  `perl`?

I also thought about `lex`, but am I really after a compiler compiler?!

---

Edit: the input is several thousand of HTML files, the prefix + regular expression would be `https://([-.0-9A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,})` (of which I want `$1`), and the rest of the input ignored.

Comment: Example please. What do you mean by "prefix"?

Comment: "https://" would be the prefix.

Comment: What do you mean by "regexp?"  Examples of the strings would help.

Comment: Why do you think grep is not a solution?  Sounds like it will work just fine with the right expression, but without more details and input samples we're all just guessing.

Comment: Amended the question.

Comment: I don't get it.  Why was this put [on hold], after the problem was clarified, and a proper solution was posted?  What's there that's unclear and requires further amendment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you won't have more than one of the pattern on a single line, I'd probably use `sed`:

```
sed -n -e 's%.*https://\([-.0-9A-Za-z]\{1,\}\.[A-Za-z]\{2,\}\).*%\1%p'
```

Given the data file:

```
Nothing here
Before https://example.com after
https://example.com and after
Before you get to https://www.example.com
And double your https://example.com for fun and happiness https://www.example.com in triplicate https://a.bb
and nothing here
```

The `sed` script produces one entry per line, showing the last entry when there's more than one on the line:

```
example.com
example.com
www.example.com
a.bb
```

A Perl script can be used for multiple entries per line:

```
$ perl -nle 'print $1 while (m%https://([-.0-9A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,})%g);' data
example.com
example.com
www.example.com
example.com
www.example.com
a.bb
$
```

Comment: I have no clue what the html input is; I'd like to be able to find more than one occurrence of my pattern on any given line.