# Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "9A"

Tags: perl

Why am I getting a syntax error?

```
% perl -ne 'if (/https://([-.0-9A-Za-z]+\.[-0-9A-Za-z]+)/) { print $1 ; }'
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "9A"
        (Missing operator before A?)
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "9A"
        (Missing operator before A?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near "9A"
syntax error at -e line 1, near ";}"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: You weren't paying attention to my answer to your question on [`sed`, `awk`, `perl` or `lex` — find strings by prefix+regex ignoring rest of input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20233796/). It demonstrated the techniques shown in the answers here.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I did this independently (based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/20172099/1122270) and when your answer only had `sed` in it (note the missing `-l` here, too), but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the regex contains slashes, use a different character and the explicit `m` operator:

```
perl -ne 'if (m%https://([-.0-9A-Za-z]+\.[-0-9A-Za-z]+)%) { print $1 ; }'
```

Or:

```
perl -ne 'print $1 if m{https://([-.0-9A-Za-z]+\.[-0-9A-Za-z]+)}'
```

Answer (score 3):

You need backslashes in front of the // after https:

```
perl -ne 'if (/https:\/\/([-.0-9A-Za-z]+\.[-0-9A-Za-z]+)/) { print $1 ; }'
```

Otherwise it thinks the regex is already over.

Comment: duh, makes sense! \o\ |o| /o/  Is there any other way, to avoid the hand waving? ^_^